# How to load image from database into android ImageView using "setImageURI" function?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-imageview, android-glide

I have to set image in Image view. I used Glide library to set image in recycler view, now when I click to recycler view item I want to set it into another activity.

I just take image url through intent and store it as a string variable.

```
final String image = intent.getStringExtra("Image");
```

Then I tried to set image using the following line of code.

```
displayImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(image));
```

Note: displayImage is my targeted imageview.

And I could get the correct url here.

Comment: Why not use Glide again to set the image on 2nd activity?

Comment: well, I used it here again.. problem fixed...Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can not display image from `URL` using [**`setImageURI();`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageURI(android.net.Uri))

You need to pass url to your activity than display it using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Use this

```
RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
requestOptions.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_placeholder);
requestOptions.error(R.drawable.ic_error);

Glide.with(this)
     .load(image)
     .apply(requestOptions)
     .into(displayImage);
```

Instead of this

```
displayImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(image));
```

Comment: Thank you..!! I just used Glide again to load image ..The problem fixed..

Answer (score 0):

Well when you have already set image once in `RecyclerView` why not use `Bitmap` from that `ImageView`. This will save network data and time.

```
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bs);
intent.putExtra("byteArray", bs.toByteArray()); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in target activity

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra("byteArray")) {
            Bitmap bitmap =
                    BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray"), 0, getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray").length);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
```